# Exception with loading .clp file in CLIPS.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fuzzy-logic, clips

I'm trying to integrate CLIPS with visual studio, I'm using CLIPS.Net, and I have a problem with the load function, I get Exception

```
Failed to load file 'test.clp'
```

I tried to replace my file with the file in the samples, and I get the exception again! my file is working in the Clips and I have tested it.
Can you help me please?

Comment: In wich folder do you have the file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the full path to the file?